# Black screen with white command line cursor when booting from clonned HDD

Tags: boot, live-usb, gparted, boot-repair, clone

I clonned the portable ubuntu from my usb stick to my laptop (hdd ~500gb) using a Gparted live usb. Now, when trying to boot from the hdd it only shows the white pointer and nothing else.

I formated the hdd before coppying everything.

I've tried Clonezilla and it didn't see the usb drive as a source, even after being manually unmounted and mounted back.

EDIT: What I mean by portable ubuntu was that I installed the OS on the usb stick as you normally would on any internal drive. Not live usb.

Comment: I don't think GParted clones the bootloader, just the partitions. I have had success using dd to clone USB to HDD, both Persistent and Full install, but it will wipe everything on the HDD and takes a long time. One problem with a persistent install is that any flash drive you try to boot will try to use the internals casper-rw.

Answer (score 0):

Cloning Portable Ubuntu, even a non-LiveUSB installation of Ubuntu, from a USB flash drive onto an HDD won't set up Ubuntu properly.

https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0 shows the proper procedure for installing Ubuntu from a LiveUSB according to Canonical, the devleopers and publishers of Ubuntu.

It requires you first make a LiveUSB with an Ubuntu installer. Here are instructions to [make it on a Windows PC](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0) and to [make it on an Ubuntu PC](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0).

Comment: What I meant by portable ubuntu was that I installed the OS on the usb stick as you normally would on any internal drive. Not live usb.

Comment: @Zombrix Still won't work. The installer does a lot you haven't done to the system drive.